# Why is my output wrong at these two test cases?

Tags: c, loops

My two test cases 18 and 20 are not getting the expected output.

I have written a code where the user has to type an integer which should be less that 100 and it should print `Weird` or `Not Weird`based on the following conditions:
"If n is odd, print `Weird`",
"If n is even and in the inclusive range of 2 to 5, print `Not Weird`",
"If n is even and in the inclusive range of 6 to 20, print `Weird`",
"If n is even and greater than 20, print `Not Weird`". Running the code with test cases as 18 and 20, it should print `Weird` for both the cases but instead the result is `Not Weird`.

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    scanf("%d",&i);
    if (i%2==0)
    {
        if(1<i<6)
        {
            printf("Not Weird");
        }
        else if(6<=i<=20)
        {
            printf("Weird");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Not Weird");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Weird");
    }
return 0;
}
```

I have tried with other test cases and they show the expected output but the problem only occurs with 18 and 20. Kindly help me with the bug.

Comment: `1<i<6` and `6<=i<=20` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: Are you sure about what this `if(1<i<6)` does? `i<6` will be `0` or `1` so `1` is never less than that.

Comment: too much python made you think that C also had operator chaining but it does not :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Or maybe too much maths

Comment: that's where python is just awesome because this operator chaining feature is super intuitive (and sometimes causes disasters in python too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
1<i<6
```

This is parsed as two separate comparisons:

```
((1<i)<6)
```

This first checks if `i` is less than 1.  This evaluates to either 0 or 1.  Then that value is checked to see if it is less than 6.  Both 0 and 1 are less than 6, so this always evaulates to true.

You instead want:

```
(i < 1) && (i < 6)
```

The same applies to `6<=i<=20`

Answer (score 1):

C does not support statements like this:

```
if(1<i<6)
```

You want:

```
if( (1<i) && (i<6) )
```

*Translation:*

If `i is greater than 1`, ***and also*** `i is less than 6`, then...